# I've made project in DNN and after created a solution of it i knew that my database of dnn is not created in sql server

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've made project in DNN and after created a solution of it i knew that my database of dnn is not created in sql server but my database is in app-folder with .mdf file . so can anybody give me solution for how to get that database in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You can "attach" the database in SSMS, I would do that by copying the files to your normal location for your databases, and attach from that location, instead of attaching to the app_data folder.